# Как разбить длинную строку на несколько в VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите пожалуйста такую настройку или плагин для VSCode, чтобы можно было разбивать длинные строки (длина которых превышает editor.ruler) на несколько строк, как это делает Geany:

[image: пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не прошло и пол года, но мне таки удалось найти [этот](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=troelsdamgaard.reflow-paragraph) чудесный плагин!